# Voice-enabled QnA bot

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, pi-4

I want to develop a custom voice-enabled QnA bot. I am relatively new to the raspberry pi. I want to know if such a project is possible with this kind of hardware that raspberry pi offers. Please suggest the pi model that I should get for such a project along with specifications. Also, tell me what are the various APIs that I can use for such a project keeping in mind that they should be compatible with the hardware.

Comment: your question is not about the RPi ... it is a linux question ... do your research in the linux realm